# jquery prevent default does not work

Tags: jquery

I want to change image when user click on a thumb image, and prevent it to jump to the top of page.

the first code I wrote:

```
$('#photos-list img').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var imgObj = new Image();
    var targetObj = $('#main_image img');
    imgObj.onload = function() {
        targetObj.attr('src',this.src);

    }
    imgObj.src = $(this).attr('rel');
});
```

the preventDefault() works fine. ok, I want to add some effects to the image changing, like fade in, I add some jquery effects in

```
$('#photos-list img').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var imgObj = new Image();
    var targetObj = $('#main_image img');
    imgObj.onload = function() {
        targetObj.hide();
        targetObj.attr('src',this.src);
        targetObj.fadeIn('normal');

    }
    imgObj.src = $(this).attr('rel');
});
```

and this time , the preventDefault does not work, even I gave fadeIn() a preventdefault like:

```
targetObj.fadeIn('normal', function(e1){e1.preventDefault();});
```

any methods to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: I think that it jumps back up

Comment: It shouldn't normally matter, but there is a semicolon missing after the first }.

Answer (score 4):

try to end function with

```
return false;
```

Comment: That is what prevenDefault does. It serves the same purpose. Must be an error somewhere

Comment: it;s not exactly the same, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Answer (score 2):

You must be getting an error for the preventDefault to fail (although the js looks ok at first glance). Have you got firebug? Is that the exact source?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable ie support.

Try the following:

```
$('#photos-list img').click(function(event) {
var ev = event || window.event;
ev.preventDefault();
// ... the rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback of the jQuery fadeIn function didn't receive an event parameter.

I asume you have the following structure:

```
<div id="#photos-list>
  <a href="#"><img src="..." /></a>
</div>
```

So try this:

```
$('#photos-list a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work:

```
if(event.preventDefault){
    event.preventDefault();
}else{
    event.returnValue = false; 
};
```